# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape the link of image from :
url='https://www.hydac.com/shop/en/1250064#simple-downloads'

Here is the error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

I dont know what is going wrong. Here is my code:

```
r=requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')

images=soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'fotorama__stage__frame fotorama_vertical_ratio fotorama__loaded fotorama__loaded--img fotorama__active'})

all_images=images.find_all('img')
for image in all_images:
    print(image['src'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that
`images=soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'fotorama__stage__frame fotorama_vertical_ratio fotorama__loaded fotorama__loaded--img fotorama__active'})`
will find something.

What is happening here is that it is finding nothing, since it tells you that `images` is a NoneType (therefore has no `find_all` attribute)

So you should add an if statement to handle this edge case where it does not find anything.

Comment: thanks for your answer but how can I scrape it? I dont know why my code doesnt find anything

Comment: your code assumes that the page is static (simple html file served by the webserver). but usually sites are dynamically populated using javascript, therefore your `requests.get` does not execute the javascript (test this using curl or wget - `wget -qO- 'https://www.hydac.com/shop/en/1250064#simple-downloads' > wget.txt`). you will need to use a tool like selenium to run the javascript engine and have it look exactly as what you see in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

To get image link of main product photo you can use next example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.hydac.com/shop/en/1250064#simple-downloads"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
print(soup.select_one('[alt="main product photo"]')["data-src"])
```

Prints:

```
https://www.hydac.com/shop/media/catalog/crossbase/cache/804510ce68ff34894246cc79cc94a424/PRD_PHO_3D/PRD_PHO_3D_10000020495-00002__SALL__AIN__V1.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you for all the help, how did you get the value of alt?

Comment: @Baroo. I did `print(soup)` and searched where is the tag holding the main photo.